# Calculate the average value of a coin in possession

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The following Google sheet contains transactions in crypto currencies. One line can represent a "buy" or a "sell" of a crypto coin:
[image: image of transactions]

What I'm trying to achieve is to calculate the average price paid for a specific coin that is still in the wallet.

In the example above that would be:

- Quantity: 0.74915977
- Average price: 133.15 EUR because we sold all coins before we bought new ones

Simply calculating the average will result in 116.93 EUR which is incorrect.

What is the correct formula to achieve the desired result of 133.15 EUR?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [averageIfs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534?hl=en&ref_topic=3105600) which allows you to stipulate conditions for which records to include. This way you can only include records where Type=Buy and Ticker=AXS. This example would look like this
`=AVERAGEIFS(C:C, J:J, "Buy", H:H, "AXS")`.

Yet to know which coin remains in your wallet may require you do create a column which tracks this. Currently I am unable to tell which coin remains in your wallet, I can only see what has been sold and what has been bought, and these two things are not the same (having, trading).

Comment: If you know what is bought and you know what is sold, it should be possible to calculate what's still in the wallet. Or am I missing something?

Comment: In that case which you describe you only have the current amount balance for a particular ticker. This would not make sense to average, as you can only ever have one value.

If you want to calculate the current amount balance then you could sum up all the records you bought and subtracts from the sum of sold records, e.g. `=SUMIFS(C:C, H:H, "AXS", J:J, "Buy") - SUMIFS(C:C, H:H, "AXS", J:J, "Sell")`